# Activity Monitor missing process arguments

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

Is there a way to tell Activity Monitor to show me the process arguments the same way ps does for example?

So instead of this (Activity Monitor):

[image: ActivityMontior]

I would like to see this (ps):

[image: ps]

If this is impossible in Activity Monitor, is there any other application that can do it? I have tried the latest htop from http://hisham.hm/htop but interestingly it is having the same issue. htop on Linux however was always showing process arguments similar to ps.

Comment: For the `htop` port, I believe that you need `sudo` to see arguments. As for Activity Manager, I don't believe you can. It's designed to be simple for average users.

Comment: Even sudo does not help htop, it still displays /usr/bin/java.

Comment: I would like to correct my comment above, the htop port (brew install htop-osx) does indeed show the arguments using sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: it is not possible to make Activity Monitor show the arguments, however using htop from the "htop" package does exactly what I want:

```
$ brew search htop
    htop ✔     htop-osx

$ htop
```